# how to change the text 'no data' in google pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

if i am passing empty data for chart binding it shows 'no data' i need to change the text 'no data' to some other word.

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day']

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do it manually:

```
if(data.getNumberOfRows() == 0){
    $("#piechart").append("Sorry, not info available")
}else{
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);        
}
```

Comment: is there any option in chart plugin itself ?

Comment: No, but data.getNumberOfRows() is from plugin

Answer (score 0):

As juvian said `data.getNuberOfRows()` is in the plugin, so if you are good with jquery you can even replace " `$("#piechart").append("Sorry, not info available")`" with an image for example

```
if (data.getNumberOfRows() == 0) {

   $("#someimage").attr("src","url-to-image");//Or any jquery dom manipulation here

} else {

var chart = new 
google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
chart.draw(data, options);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace text in SVG after chart drawing

```
chart.draw(data, options);
if (data.getNumberOfRows() == 0) {
    $("#piechart").find("svg text").text("Your text")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on [newbedev.com](https://newbedev.com/how-to-show-an-empty-google-chart-when-there-is-no-data) and here is how I had to modify it.

```
var data = [ [ 'Label', 'Count' ] ];
var options = { sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0 };

// add your data to the array.

if (data.length == 1) {
    data.push(['', 0]);
    options.sliceVisibilityThreshold = 0.01;
}

var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(this.data);
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
chart.draw(chartData, options);
```

The `sliceVisibilityThreshold` determines when a slice will be visible on its own within the chart. If it is set to zero, then all slices show. Ensuring the threshold is greater than zero and having at least one entry set to zero is the key. The single slice will not be visible, the legend will not display, and the "No data" message is gone.